# div won't position itself correctly with a fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have a header with `position:fixed`. Within this header there is a div which is of a variable height, with `min-height: 60px`

Now, there is a div called container below the header div which has the following css:

```
width: 1007px;
padding: 60px 0 0 0;
display: block;
```

Now this works fine as long as the header is 60px, but when the header height increases, the top of the container gets hidden by the header. How do I go about fixing this so that if the height of the header changes dynamically to say 90px, the container div will just move below, according to this new height?

Html is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <header style="width: 100%; display: block; position: fixed; z-index: 1;">
    <div class="b-block" style="min-height:60px;display: block;">blah blah</div>
 </header>
 <div id="container" style="width: 1007px; padding: 60px 0 0 0; display: block;">blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that that's not possible with **CSS** because the `container` isn't _fixed_ like `header`. Nevertheless, here's a [JQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/57hvR/).

Comment: The problem is on that position : fixed set on the <header>

Comment: @Vucko - thanks, sadly, your solution didn't work, as when I added content to the div in the header in the element inspector to increase the height, the container dv didn't move down.

Comment: @user1038814 my mistake,[try now](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/57hvR/1/).

Comment: thanks for trying Vucko, but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is normal behavior since the header has fixed positioning. The only way to achieve what you want, if the header content changes, is to change the padding of the #container dynamically, with javascript.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/milpv

You get the height of the header and set it as top padding for the #container div.